# Node.js Express framework generate broken app.js?

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I'm new in Node.js and would like to crete a simple application with Express.

```
npm install -g express
npm install -g ejs

express test -t ejs
cd test/
npm install
```

Now i have an application skeleton. But it is broken. For example my app.js content is

```
,/**, * Module dependencies., */,,var express = require('express'),  , routes = require('./routes'),  , user = require('./routes/user'),  , http = require('http'),  , path = require('path');,,var app = express();,,// all environments,app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);,app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');,app.set('view engine', 'jade');,app.use(express.favicon());,app.use(express.logger('dev'));,app.use(express.bodyParser());,app.use(express.methodOverride());,app.use(app.router);,app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));,,// development only,if ('development' == app.get('env')) {,  app.use(express.errorHandler());,},,app.get('/', routes.index);,app.get('/users', user.list);,,http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){,  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));,});,
```

And after 'node app' it throw with

```
C:\Users\saxon\Downloads\123\test\app.js:1
,/**, * Module d
^

node.js:201
    throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
          ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,
    at Module._compile (module.js:429:25)
    at Object..js (module.js:459:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:348:31)
    at Function._load (module.js:308:12)
    at Array.0 (module.js:479:10)
at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:192:40)
```

Answer (score 2):

Problem is solved:
My installed version was 0.6.xxx, now is 0.10.xxx
reinstall all packages (ejs, express, connect, request)

Comment: Great, I find this tutorial good for getting up and running http://blog.ijasoneverett.com/2013/03/a-sample-app-with-node-js-express-and-mongodb-part-1/